# How can I do a crossfade with angular animate and ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I'm triggering an animation when I update the collection I pass into `*ngFor`:

```
//JS
state : string = 'a';
colors = {
  a: ['red','blue','green','yellow'],
  b: ['orange']
}

public onClick (){
  this.state = this.state === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a';
}

//HTML
<div *ngFor="let color of colors[state]" 
   [@animationState]="state" 
   (click)="onClick()">
     {{color}}
</div>
```

**The problem:** While the animation is happening, colors from both `a` and `b` display, which makes the animation jerky.

**I've tried:**

- setting `transform: scale(0)` or `display:none` before the `void => *` animation begins
- delaying the `void => *` animation by the duration of the `* => void` animation

**I want:** to smoothly fade and/or slide out my existing content before (or while) the new content fades/slides in.

Here's a plunkr that demonstrates the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/IDE6q6lJ84QI2Zirvn4P?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work, but it feels like a hack. Instead of setting the `ngFor` collection to the new value immediately, I

1. store the new value in a temp variable
2. set the `ngFor` collection to an empty collection
3. when the animation to an empty collection completes, update the collection to the value stored in the temp variable

This triggers *two* animations instead of one, but seems to work well.

```
//JS
state : string = 'a';
temp : string;
colors = {
  a: ['red','blue','green','yellow'],
  b: ['orange'],
  empty: []
}

public onClick (){
  this.temp = this.state === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a';
  this.state = 'empty'
}

public animationComplete(){
  if(this.temp){
    this.state = this.temp;
    this.temp = undefined;
  }
}

//HTML
<div *ngFor="let color of colors[state]" 
   [@animationState]="state" 
   (@animationState.done)="animationComplete()"
   (click)="onClick()">
     {{color}}
</div>
```